# Yii Cgridview $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection function doesn't work right away

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have a cgridview on a yii application, and I have selectableRows set to only 1.
I have the following javascript to catch the click event and copy the id of the row into a  texfield on the same view file (the id can't be shown on the gridview itself that's why I'm using getSelection).

```
$('#doctors-grid').on('click', 'table tbody tr', function() 
        {       
            var doctorID = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('doctors-grid');   
            $('#doctorIDTextfield').val(doctorID);      
        });
```

The problem is that the id value is never copied into the textfield on the first click but instead you have to click a second time. Not to mention that when I start clicking many different rows the id values get wrong some times.

Can anyone help? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk why it doesn't work, but you can do it another way:

```
....
    'rowHtmlOptionsExpression'=>'array("data-id"=>$data->id)',
....
```

in your grid options,then with js:

```
$('#doctors-grid').on('click', 'table tbody tr', function() 
        {       
            var doctorID = $(this).attr("data-id");   
            $('#doctorIDTextfield').val(doctorID);      
        });
```

This will work.